# Tensorboard not showing time series graphs when accessed within google cola

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am trying to use tensorboard within google colab using the code below:

```
%reload_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir=/content/gdrive/MyDrive/content/training/train
```

However when tensorboard loads, I am not able to see anything.
I have tried it both when the model is training and after training.

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi @Gkl, Could you please refer to this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_in_notebooks) and let us know if it helps or not. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create TensorBoard callbacks and pass the path of the directory where to save the log files to be parsed by TensorBoard. Make sure that this directory should not be reused by any other callbacks.

```
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir)
```

when training the model pass this tensorboard_callabacks to model.fit()

```
model.fit(callbacks=tensorboard_callback)
```

After training you can load the tensorboard using

```
%tensorboard --logdir logs
```

For more details please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/8103295f07c0a9dd4d9a71e731afb13a). Thank You.